# Scrolling 2 or more collectionview synchronously

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have 2 horizontal uicollectionview. How to scroll 2nd collection view at same time when you scroll 1st.

Comment: Have you tried anything out?

Comment: just play with     scrollView_obj.scrollEnabled = TRUE;

Comment: please explain your question a little bit and provide us with an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `UICollectionView` is also a `UIScrollView` and as such, its delegate receives all  `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods.

You should implement `scrollViewDidScroll:` in the delegates of both your collection views. In the implementation of the method, you can then adjust the `contentOffset` of the other collection view according to the `contentOffset` of the view that has been scrolled.